# Resolve a promise once in a racing time

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

Here is a Promise:

`var getVersion = new Promise(function(resolve){
    getVersionAsyn(resolve);
});`

<del>Then a lot of http requests depend on that 'version' and the requests send in the same time.</del>

When page initial, a lot of http requests will send to server and the request are depend on 'version'.

How to prevent `getVersion` promise run multiple times?

---

All right. I down vote myself. Such a idiot question.

Comment: _"Then a lot of http requests depend on that 'version' and the requests send in the same time"_ What is text of `getVersionAsyn` ? Which function makes multiple `HTTP` requests?

Comment: What is purpose of passing `resolve` to `getVersionAsyn` function?

Comment: _"How to prevent `getVersion` promise run multiple times?"_  Why would `getVersion` be called multiple times? Not certain what expected result is? Prevent multiple requests from occurring? Or prevent function from being called recursively? Though no recursion appears at Question?

Comment: ```getVersionAsyn```is a async function, so the argument 'resove' is a sort of 'callback'. ```getVersionAsyn```will run multiple time if http request need version every time.

Comment: _"so the argument 'resove' is a sort of 'callback'"_ What do you mean by "sort of 'callback'"? Is `resolve` called within `getVersionAsyn` function? How would `getVersion` be called multiple times? A `Promise` can be fulfilled or rejected at most once.

Comment: Can you show us the actual code for `getVersionAsyn()` so we can see what it does and how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to prevent getVersion promise run multiple times?

You are already caching the promise and thus the resolved value of the version so `getVersionAsyn()` only ever gets called once.  You can have as many `.then()` handlers as you want on a promise and all the subsequent once do is just fetch the saved, resolved value out of the promise data structure.  They don't "execute" anything else over and over again.

The way this code works:

```
var getVersion = new Promise(function(resolve){
    getVersionAsyn(resolve);
});
```

`getVersion` is a promise and you are already storing it.  You can have as many callers as you do this:

```
getVersion.then(function(version) {
    // access the version here
});
```

And, `getVersionAsyn()` will only ever be called just once, the first time.  From then on, once the promise has resolved, you will just be accessing the saved resolved value (essentially an automatic cache).  It is actually a nice design pattern to use promise for caching and async-retrieved value.

Comment: `getVersion.then(function(version) {
    // access the version here
});` Would `version` be accessible at `.then()` where no value is `return`ed from `getVersion`? Also, `resolve` does appear to actually be called?

Comment: @guest271314 - Sorry, but I don't understand that comment.  `getVersion` is a promise.  Using `.then()` on it will return whatever the resolved value of that promise is whether you call it once or 100 times.  Promises never change their resolved value.

Comment: Is `resolve` called at `javascript` at Answer? Or passed as a reference to `getVersionAsyn`? Note, requirement at Question is not clear, here.

Comment: @guest271314 - `resolve` is passed as a function reference to `getVersionAsyn()`.  I've ask the OP to provide us code for `getVersionAsyn()` so we can see what it does.

Comment: Not aware of what `getVersionAsyn()` call does? Text of function is not included at Question. Though if `resolve` is not actually called at `getVersionAsyn` no value can be passed to `.then()` as `getVersion` `Promise` would have a `pending` "state". _"I don't understand your comment."_ That is, `resolve` does not fulfill `getVersion`, `resolve()` would

Comment: If any other function try to resolve ```getVersion``` when it pending. It will still execute ```getVersionAsyn``` again.

Comment: @JamesYin _"If any other function try to resolve getVersion when it pending. It will still execute getVersionAsyn again."_ How could another function resolve `getVersion`? Where is `Promise` created within `getVersion` actually resolved? Question and comments are not clear, here. Can you create a stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: @JamesYin - No.  You have it wrong.  If you are using `getVersion.then()`, then you can execute that 20 times and it will not ever execute the `getVersionAsyn()` function again.  That was already done once and only once when the `getVersion` promise was initially created.  Promises are just a data structure with a couple methods.  Using `.then()` on them doesn't execute any functions.   The function was execute first and that created the promise.

Comment: @guest271314, so sorry of my English. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w32u9x48)

Comment: @JamesYin - And, what's the actual problem in that jsFiddle that you want help with?  `getVersion` is a promise.  The code inside the new Promise executor function is only ever executed once.

Comment: Those ajax requests will make ```getVersion``` ```getName```run twice.

Comment: @JamesYin - No, they will NOT.  Put a `console.log("Inside getVersion()")` statement inside the `setTimeout()` in the getVersion promise.  It will only ever execute ONCE.  You aren't understanding that `getVersion` is a promise.  It doesn't execute code.  Sending it to `Promise.all()` ONLY gets the value out of the promise and/or waits for the original execution to finish.  It NEVER causes it to execute anything again.  `getVersion` is NOT a function (and thus it has kind of a misleading name).  It's a promise.

Comment: @JamesYin What is expected result? Note, `Promise` at `ajax` function at https://jsfiddle.net/w32u9x48 is not actually resolved or rejected, `resolve()` is not called.

Comment: Your ajax function should do return `Promise.all(...)` and get rid of the `new Promise(...)`.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's strange. I write almost the same code in my project. But it run multiple times. I read MDN document too. It said that Promise is only  run once too. I need to debug more...

Answer (score 1):

Keep the result of the `getVersion` in the execution context of the subsequent promises...

```
getVersion.then(version => {
    var reqA = doHttp(version, "request A");
    var reqB = doHttp(version, "request B");
    var reqC = doHttp(version, "request C");
    return Promise.all([reqA, reqB, reqC]);
});
```

Comment: But how about the http request after page initial? Do I need to resolve ```getVersion```again?

Comment: Formed the way I suggest, all of those http requests will have access to the same `version` result, run only once, but before any of the requests that depend upon it.